# Copy content from one db to external db

Tags: php, mysql

I have a webshop `db` where i want to export some things linke order information to another external `db` on another `server` etc.

Example of things to move:

```
Table1
  - orderid
  - orderdate
Table2
  - adress
  - shippingmethod
```

I ONLY want it to export and import things that is not currently there.

How can this be done in a php script?

Comment: `SELECT` & `INSERT/UPDATE` ?

Comment: may be this contain what you want. please check http://befused.com/php/select-insert-different-databases

Comment: Regarding the befused link, how would this work in with 2 dbs on different servers?